# How to extract string type values from two columns using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to filter unique values from two columns using Pandas. 
Column A and Column B have some overlapping values. I want to create a new column C to extract unique values from Column A, which does not appear in Column B. An outcome would like the following example.

```
    Column A    Column B     Column C
      aaa         aaa           xyz
      bbb         bbb           str
      xyz
      str
```

Can someone help me with this question?

Comment: Easiest way would just be: `df['Column C'] = df.loc[~df['Column A'].isin(df['Column B']), 'Column A']`

Comment: Thank you for your help!